# Display images from local folder to datalist using Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

I am displaying images  from my application to datalist.Source code is:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlist" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" CellPadding="5">
<ItemTemplate><asp:Image Width="100" ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Name", "~/Images/{0}") %>' runat="server" />
<br /></ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle BorderColor="Brown" BorderStyle="dotted" BorderWidth="3px" HorizontalAlign="Center"VerticalAlign="Bottom" />`
</asp:DataList>
```

code behind is

```
  protected void BindDataList()
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MapPath("Images"));
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    ArrayList listItems = new ArrayList();
    foreach (FileInfo info in files)
    {
        listItems.Add(info);
    }
    dtlist.DataSource = listItems;
    dtlist.DataBind();

}
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    fileupload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Images/" + filename));
    BindDataList();

}
```

As this I want to display all the images from local drive to data list. ex from `C:\Sales n purchases\ImagesFolder` to datalist.

please any one help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image Width="100" ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("{1}\\{0}", Eval("Name"), Eval("Directory")) %>'
            runat="server" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label id="lblImageSrc" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("{1}\\{0}", Eval("Name"), Eval("Directory")) %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I am new to asp.net. I ahve given the Directory as   <%# String.Format("{1}\\{0}", Eval("Name"), Eval(@"C:\Sales n purchases\ImagesFolder")) %>.. it is throwing an error

Comment: No need to change anything in (my) above code snippet. Just replace whole asp:Image tag with your existing asp:image tag.

Comment: Sorry.. It is working,but showing .gif images only.. why?? I want to display .jpg,.bmp too

Comment: I am not able to reproduce such type issue. Can you please try with another images?

Comment: I have deleted the images in that path and again save it.. Now .gif too not displaying.. its is only showing empty images

Comment: I have update above code snippet. In this code i have added label to show the image URL. Can you please check that in this location file is exists or not.

In-addition also clear your browser history and cache.

Comment: It is showing the image path too. but image is not displaying. showing an empty.

Comment: Can you please create new sample web site/web application and check this issue in it? Because i am not able to reproduce this at my hand.